# How can i draw a rectangle using Java and the JFrame class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, drawing

Im about to learn Java (after C++) now,and I am trying myself in Gui Programming.

My goal in this code was to draw something simple into a window created with the JFrame library.

This is my code:

```
import gui.Gui;

public class Main
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Gui g = new Gui();
        g.paint(null);
    }
}
```

---

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Gui extends JFrame
{
    public Gui()
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Beispiel JFrame");
        jf.setTitle("Draw Something");
        jf.setSize(960, 960);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("./img.png");
        jf.setIconImage(img.getImage());       
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(480, 480, 200, 100);
    }
}
```

it compiles without an error message, but it draws nothing.
I am unable to find the reason for that, could anyone help me :) ?

(And sry if the formatting is not "perfect", I am new to StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

It's generally recommend that you NOT extend from a top level container like `JFrame`.  You're not adding any new functionality to the class and you're locking yourself into a single use case.  `JFrame` is also a compound component, that is, it contains a number of child components which make up its core functionality, and, because of the way the painting system works, it's possible for a child component to painted independently of the parent container/component, which, in your case, is going to produce a lot of issues.

[image]

I would recommend you start by reading through [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) to get a better understanding of how the paint system works and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to better understand how you should work with it.

You probably also want to read through the [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) trail.

Also, as a general rule of thumb, unless you're willing to take over the full responsibility of the method you're overriding, you should be calling its `super` implementation.  In this case, painting is complex workflow, so you've basically completely circumvented it, which is not going to end well.

Back to your problem, instead of using `JFrame` and overriding `paint` (which is generally un-recommended), you should start with something like `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` instead, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth() / 4;
            int height = getHeight() / 2;
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```